# Ubuntu 16 detects wifi networks but cannot connect to new networks, also no wifi icon!

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I have had Ubuntu 16 for 1.5 years now and had no issues until 3 months ago when my laptop would not connect to new wifi networks i.e. it connects automatically to those that I had passwords saved and while it detects new available networks I cannot connect to those, also nothing happens if I try clicking on settings for these in network manager. I don't even know where to begin. Thanks.

Output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095b] (rev 99)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5210]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
```

Comment: Does your Computer recognize the NIC? Run `sudo lspci -v` to check that.

Comment: @ValentinBauer How could it not recognize the NIC when *it connects automatically to those that I had passwords saved (...)*? By telepathy or what?

Comment: In order to identify your hardware please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. This is for completeness only. The problem is unlikely to be related to a specific hardware but proposed solutions may need to be tailored accordingly.

Comment: Hey MichaelBay I have now added the output of that command.  But this is from a location where I'm able to use the wifi. Thanks.